# VS2013 Razor and Format Document

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Formatting this part of code via Ctrl+E, D:

```cs
if (row % 3 == 0)
    {
       @:</div>
    }
```

gives me:

```cs
if (row % 3 == 0)
    {
       @:
      </div>
    }
```

which makes my .cshtml document invalid. 
Any suggestions on how to prevent this in VS2013, but that my other code still gets proper formatting using Ctrl+E, D?

Comment: Apparently the javascript snippets mustn't be indented when you enter them before the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same issue as you. The only way I managed to stop it was by rewriting it like this (you won't need the initial `@` before the `if` as long as you are already in a code block, but I did when I pasted it into my page to test it):

```cs
@if (row % 3 == 0)
{
    @Html.Raw("</div>")
}
```

I first learnt about using `@:` as a replacement for when [@Html.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740) didn't work.

Comment: You could probably also do `<text></div></text>`.

Comment: I've added the Html.Raw method, hope this will be fixed soon.
extra info: http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-vs-text-tag-vs-html-raw